# Tomcat Running but Not Responding to New Request

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, nio, comet

Our application is developed using CometProcessor to serve long live connections.

However, after multiple connections established and then dropped (at any time, there are only 200 connections running). The Tomcat will stop responding to new request.

This is the the configuration in **server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" acceptCount="50" processorCache="50" connectionTimeout="20000" keepAliveTimeout="20000" maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" maxThreads="500" acceptorThreadCount="2" maxConnections="-1" redirectPort="8443" />
```

And the Tomcat is started with the following **JAVA_OPTS**

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxNewSize=768m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Xss4096k -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

The server has **3.7GB RAM and 2 CPU Cores**.

When this happens, we also saw many TCP connections go to CLOSE_WAIT state.

```
tcp6       1      0 10.36.0.29:8080         119.75.45.206:22621     CLOSE_WAIT  2936/java
tcp6       1      0 10.36.0.29:8080         10.36.0.85:50096        CLOSE_WAIT  2936/java
..
```

It can go as many as 200-300 connections in CLOSE_WAIT state

And when I check on the parent PID status:

```
Name:   java
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   2936
Ngid:   0
Pid:    2936
PPid:   1
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    104     104     104     104
Gid:    107     107     107     107
FDSize: 1024
Groups: 107
VmPeak:  5583268 kB
VmSize:  5558668 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:    405980 kB
VmRSS:    405980 kB
VmData:  5452352 kB
VmStk:       136 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:     23304 kB
VmPTE:      2076 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        235
SigQ:   0/15034
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000001002
SigCgt: 2000000181004ccd
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
Seccomp:        0
Cpus_allowed:   7fff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-14
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:      0
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     2
```

And the limits is:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             15034                15034                processes
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       15034                15034                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

HTOP shows that the CPU is running <5% and Memory is 843MB/3774MB. And nothing shown in Tomcat Log, in fact, all of the new request is not logged in the catalina.out at all.

So, I tried to strace the PID:

```
sudo strace -p 2936
Process 2936 attached
futex(0x7f23022749d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 2937, NULL
```

Found that this a bug in the old Linux kernel, however, we have also updated the Linux Kernel to version 3.16:

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u2 (2016-06-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Once this happens, restarting Tomcat is the only way out.

This issue has been bothering me for a long time so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much Youcef for helping to reformat the question.

Comment: First step is to remove your code and try running a similar test against the vanilla Tomcat.  That should give us a starting point.